# Why does six.py use custom class for finding MAXSIZE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-internals, six

I was going through the code for [`six.py` in the django utils](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/six.py#L59), which, for non Jython implementations, tries, to find the MAXSIZE for the int. Now, the way this is done is interesting - instead of catching an exception on the statement itself, the statement is wrapped within a `__len__` method in a custom class. What may be the reason(s) to do so?

```
class X(object):
    def __len__(self):
        return 1 << 31
try:
    len(X())
except OverflowError:
    # 32-bit
    MAXSIZE = int((1 << 31) - 1)
else:
    # 64-bit
    MAXSIZE = int((1 << 63) - 1)
del X
```

If I'm not wrong, the same could have been shortened to the below as well, right?

```
try:
    1 << 31
except OverflowError:
    # 32-bit
    MAXSIZE = int((1 << 31) - 1)
else:
    # 64-bit
    MAXSIZE = int((1 << 63) - 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` in python3 is a poly-glot sort of class that can represent machine ints as well as big-ints;  a feature that superseedes the distinction between `int` and `long` in python2.  On python3, the construction `int(1 << n)` never throws an error.

So to solve that, six is using a neat trick that *forces* python to cram something into a machine sized int.  The `len` builtin always trys to convert the return value of `__len__` into a machine sized thing:

```
>>> class Lengthy(object):
...     def __init__(self, x):
...         self.x = x
...     def __len__(self):
...         return self.x
...     
>>> int(1<<100)
1267650600228229401496703205376L
>>> type(int(1<<100))
<type 'long'>
>>> len(Lengthy(1<<100))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-6-6b1b77348950>", line 1, in <module>
    len(Lengthy(1<<100))
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int

>>>
```

or, in Python 3, the exception is slightly different:

```
>>> len(Lengthy(1<<100))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer
>>>
```

Comment: This seems to answer it. Do you have a link for the `The len builtin always trys to convert the return value of __len__ into a machine sized thing`..?

Comment: The most relevant bit, `PyObject_Size` is defined to return a `Py_ssize_t` (see https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b4cbecbc0781/Objects/abstract.c#l43), which is ultimately the function that gets called (via a few macro indirections) by the `len` builtin.